# Display popup window even after redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, html, popupwindow, redirect

In my application, redirecting from Page1 to Page2 is taking almost 6 seconds. So meanwhile I need to display a popup window immediately on click of a hyperlink on page1, which should be there till the entire data loads on page2.

I tried to implement in normal way (open the popup on click of the hyperlink and meanwhile the page redirects to page2), but the moment page url is getting changed to page2 the popup is getting closed as the page2 DOM gets started loading. This is not my requirement. Can someone please suggest me how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought... look for a GET variable (for example `showMessage`) when Page 2 loads that would display the same popup from Page 1 so it appears to be the same message.  Sample function for your click event handler.

```
function redirectHandler(pageURL) {
  // Display Popup
  // Redirect to pageURL and append "?showMessage=true"
}
```

When the DOM is ready on Page 2, display the popup before the page's load event.

```
$( document ).ready() {
  // Get query parameters 
  // Display popup if showMessage is true
}
```

Once Page 2 completes loading, hide your popup

```
$( window ).load(function() { 
  // Remove popup 
});
```

The GET variable could also be handled server side and there would be no JS delay to handle rendering the popup.

Comment: Hi Dylan, Thanks for your inputs. But while redirecting from page1 to page2 (which is taking almost 6 seconds) this popup will go away and when page2 starts loading this will display right.. but I need to show this even at the time of redirection (the page redirection should happen behind the popup window)..

Comment: 6 seconds is painful. You might be able to speed up the second page render with the HTML `prefetch` tag on Page 1. http://davidwalsh.name/html5-prefetch

Answer (score 0):

You can open a new external popup window. It will be independent form the page that is loading in the background.

```
window.open("/href/to/page");
```

You can find more info about popups [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)